# MongoDB match if input exists (aggregation)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

```
$match: {
  date: { $gte: fromDate, $lte: toDate },
  if (userId) { 
    user: userId 
  }
},
```

I am trying to match a user only if there is a `userId` submitted. What is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [mongoose query builder](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-match), to manage aggregations stages as per your conditions,

```
// INITIALIZE
let p = YourSchemaModel.aggregate();
// DATE FILTER
p.match({ date: { $gte: fromDate, $lte: toDate } });
// USER ID FILTER
if (userId) p.match({ user: userId });
// RESULT
let result = await p.exec();
```

> Aggregation will auto merge `$match` stages if both are together!

---

Second option:

```
let result = await YourSchemaModel.aggregate().match(
  Object.assign(
    { date: { $gte: fromDate, $lte: toDate } }, 
    userId ? { user: userId } : {}
  )
).exec();
```